# All Required Name Space I can Add For my standard style sheet

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

As part of my standard style sheet I am adding below name space considering all standard operation I will be able to used while transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"
                xmlns:pre="xalan://org.apache.xalan.Version"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

So will it be enough to cover all type scenarios/flavors that I might need to handle; or is there any further namespaces /attribute that I should consider?
Specifically what all other namespaces I can use for error handling ?

Also it will be helpful if it can be identified in case I am not using any correct URI for any of the listed namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would declare only the namespaces that your stylesheet actually uses, not all those that you think you might need in future. And remember to use exclude-result-prefixes so they don't all get copied to the result tree.

From a quick look at your list, the "fn" namespace URI is incorrect, and the "xdt" one is not needed - it was used in a candidate recommendation and was dropped in the final specification.

You've tagged the question xslt 2.0, so I can't see why you would want Xalan namespaces, since that's xslt 1.0.

Comment: So I will be removing   xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan", xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" and for function xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" this will be the correct one?

Comment: Yes. But it's unlikely you actually need to declare the fn namespace. You're unlikely to be using it explicitly.